# Motion detection in iphone/android without using GPS or internet

Tags: iphone, android, motion, motion-detection

I am trying to detect motion of iphone/android without using internet or without using gps. Firstly i am not sure as to whether this is possible and if yes how to go about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more explicit when referring to "motion detection" as this could mean many things and also demonstrate some level of prior research instead of throwing out vague questions.

Comment: try looking at them. motion would / could be detected without internet / gps.

Comment: @ceejayoz why don't you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about [inertial navigation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation). While most android phones are equipped with accelerometers and compass sensors, it will be extremely difficult, if not impossible, to perform the necessary computations on the devices. Also, I don't know if the precision/accuracy of the built-in sensors are suitable for this approach.